# How to make an element inside of display:table-cell have 100% height

Tags: html, css

I've tried doing a bunch of searches but I can't seem to find any answers. I have a table with table-rows, table-cells, and then anchors inside of them. I want the anchor to stretch the whole height of its parent table-cell, but I can't seem to get this to work. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mvqvxxux/1/

```
<div class="table" role="list">
  <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell" role="listitem">
          <a class="anchor" role="button">Short text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell" role="listitem">
          <a class="anchor" role="button">Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text</a>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell" role="listitem">
          <a class="anchor" role="button">Short text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell" role="listitem">
          <a class="anchor" role="button">Short text</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know that I could make the anchor itself the table-cell and this would fix the issue, but we have to conform to accessibility standards which consider this table a "list" with "listitems" inside of it and "buttons" inside of the "listitems", as you can see in my fiddle. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you want this to happen only because the background doesnt fill it?

Comment: The background, but more importantly the clickable area.

Comment: @CBroe - I don't think you read what I wrote after the code snippet...

Comment: Would you be willing to forgo table-layout, and use flexbox instead?

Comment: (I wonder if accessibility standards would actually mind if the A were list-items and buttons at the same time ...?)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add background on table cell for full coverage.
2. Use after pseudo class to expand on whole cell. Since it is part of the link it will trigger.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width:300px;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  border:1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
}

.anchor {
  display: block;
}
.anchor:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.anchor:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table" role="list">
  <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell" role="listitem">
          <a class="anchor" role="button">Short text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell" role="listitem">
          <a class="anchor" role="button">Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell" role="listitem">
          <a class="anchor" role="button">Short text</a>
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell" role="listitem">
          <a class="anchor" role="button">Short text</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```